# Custom validator getting invoked onclick of all controls on the page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, customvalidator

i have written a custom validation function to check if a panel is displayed
i want the function to be invoked onclick of NEXT button.

But instead it gets invoked onclick of every button on the page.

Here is the code:

```
 function Validate(sender, args)
    {
        if (document.getElementById("Panel1").style.display == 'none') {
                args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
    }
```

and this is the button code onclick of which it should be invoked.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="InputButton" OnClick="btnNext_Click" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvValidate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Panel has no data." ClientValidationFunction="Validate" Display="none" EnableViewState="false"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

if i set Controltovalidate="btnNext" then it again throws me error.
"btnNext cannot be validated".

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook it to the right element.

`document.getElementById("btnNext").onclick = function() {
  //Do Your Stuff Here
};`

Angela

Comment: hi thanx 4 replying i am not very wellversed with javascript could you please tell me where should i place ur suggested code..coz if i write it onload i get the object expected error on btnNext

Comment: the page is opening with errors i am not able to see anything on the page

Answer (score 0):

Hey i did a very simple solution to my problem.
first is the java script code that ws getting invoked onclick of evry button on the page.

```
      function Validate(sender, args)
    {
        if (document.getElementById("Panel1").style.display == 'none') {
                args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
    }
```

Then on the Next button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="InputButton" OnClick="btnNext_Click" />

<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvValidate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Panel has no data." ClientValidationFunction="Validate" Display="none" EnableViewState="false"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

and for the rest of buttons i did set causesvalidation=false property. with this the function wwas getting invoked only on Next button